# Java/JSP WEB-INF/classes can't import

Tags: java, jsp

Its been a while since I had to do some Java/JSP...

I have a java class in WEB-INF/classes/MyClass.java
The build in Netbeans is successful and I can see MyClass.class in the classes folder.

In my jsp page, I've got

```
<%@ page import="MyClass" %>
```

Tomcat says that the import cannot be resolved...

I tried to put MyClass in a package(WEB-INF/com/MyClass) and then import the package into my Jsp file. The import doesnt throw an error anymore then, but I cannot instanciate a MyClass object, says the type is unresolved...

What am I doing wrong here..?

All help appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG, I found my mistake...

Netbeans wasn't copying the lib files to the right folder, my jsp page was being updated, so it looked like all the files were copied, but actually MyClass.class wasnt in the folder...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: yep. Netbeans keeps classes inside build folder. If u r using netbeans, i suggest you to get a war from it and unpack the war using tomcat(on restart tomcat automatically unpacks if that option is set to true). Then you need not worry about copying class files.

Comment: Yep that's what I'm doing now, using a war and everything works perfect!

Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 4):

```
WEB-INF/classes/MyClass.java
```

makes me guess that you're using the default package which is'nt a good practice at all. Try assigning your class to a package and do the import according to that.

Do something like:

```
package myPackage;

class myClass
{
...
}
```

And afterwards:

```
<%@ page import="myPackage.myClass" %>
```

Answer (score 3):

.class file must be placed inside the **classes** folder under **WEB-INF**.
So, the location of MyClass.class must be  WEB-INF/classes/com/ (In case **com** is a package).

```
<%
 // Instantiate a MyClass

 com.MyClass obj=new com.MyClass();

%>
```

OR

```
<%@ page import="com.MyClass" %>
<%
   MyClass obj=new MyClass();
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

What package is MyClass in? If the default package then you can put the class file in

```
WEB-INF/classes
```

if it's in a package, then use the package directory hierarchy under classes