# Problems referencing an external project from my jsp - "ExternalClass cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, project

I inherited 2 JSP projects (tomcat) in my eclipse with common code that is duplicated.
I wanted to externalize the duplicate code to common library/project and reference it from both JSP project.

So I did the following:

I created a new Java project "JSP-Common" with the following package "com.mycompany.jsp.common". There I create a class "ExternalClass" with a public "test()" method that returns a string.

in JSP1 project(one of the 2 JSP projects):

1. I added the JSP-Common project to the build path projects tab
2. I added to the jsp file in it the following import:

   ```
   <%@ page import = "com.mycompany.jsp.common.*" %>
   ```
3. I added to the jsp file in the body somewhere

   ```
   <% ExternalClass ec=new ExternalClass(); %>
   ```

After building and publishing the project, I get a "ExternalClass cannot be resolved to a type" error on the line with the instantiation above in my page.

Am I missing something ? Help ?

I want to make it so when I build my JSP1 project it will automatically take the callses from the JSP-Common project.

Comment: I also read the following which didn't help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700416/java-jsp-web-inf-classes-cant-import http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303412/jsp-page-import-problem-class-file-placed-in-a-package-inside-web-inf-classes

Comment: Are you sure your build process is creating a JAR for the Common project and including it in the WEB-INF/lib for JSP1 and JSP2 projects? What build tool are you using?

Comment: I am not building a JAR in the common project, do I have to ? when I did a simple test with a new java application project (non jsp) referencing and importing another common/shared project it works without using a JAR...

Comment: Yes, you do. Your IDE is managing your classpath for you in a way that makes it less obvious that you need to do this, but remember that you are creating a JEE app, not a JSE one.

Comment: As I am new to the eclipse environment (coming from VS), I am using springsource tool and I created the project using file->new-> java project ... I am not sure exactly it uses Ant or Maven as I use the IDE for all the build automation and when I want to create a JAR i right click the project and do Export ....

Comment: Can you please point me to a source that explains how I automate my JSP-Common project to create a JAR ? And after that I assume I only need to add the JAR to the build path of my JSP1 project (in the libraries tab ?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add JSP-Common project in Deployment Assembly: go to Deployment Assembly page under project properties. Hit Add and select "Project" option.

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly ! So after reading the comments above and your answer, am I right to assume that you can add a shared project to a JSP project with 2 methods: using a JSP-Common JAR (Perception comments in my question) and by the method you described (without using a JAR) ?